# Tree building function in Haskell (Homework)

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

unfoldTree:: (b -> Maybe (b, a, b)) -> b -> Tree a
unfoldTree f b =
    case f b of
      Nothing -> Leaf
      Just (lt, x, rt) -> Node (unfoldTree f lt) x (unfoldTree f rt)
```

Given the two piece of information above, I'm asked to implement a tree building function.

and my attempt is

```
treeBuild :: Integer -> Tree Integer
treeBuild 0 = Leaf
treeBuild n = treeUnfold (\b -> if b < 2^n-1 
                then Just(2*b, b + 1, 2*b + 1) 
                else Nothing) 
                0
```

The base case works where n = 0 works fine but I know the function is completely wrong. Can someone re-explain to me how would a `3-tuple Just` work? In a normal unfold, the first element in a `Just` would be the element I want and the second element would be used to continue unfolding but how does this work in a 3-tuple Just?

As example output:
`treeBuild 2 ----> Node (Node Leaf 0 Leaf) 1 (Node Leaf 2 Leaf)`

Edit:
I'm not completely sure how Just works here, for the case of `Just(2*b, b + 1, 2*b + 1)` where b starts at 0, does it become `Just(0, 1, 0)`? How do I actually increment b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you omitted a space when pasting the definition of `unfoldTree`. Should it be this?

```
unfoldTree f b =
    case f b of ...
```

There's nothing intrinsically meaningful about `Maybe (b, a, b)`, but in this particular case you can see that `unfoldTree` binds the items in the tuple to `lt`, `x`, and `rt`. The middle value `x` is used to create a node, and `lt` and `rt` are used to seed the recursive calls to `unfoldTree`.

To explain your example output, note that `n` is always bound to `2`. The initial `0` argument to `treeUnfold` means the `(\b -> ...)` function first checks `0 < 2^n-1`, then yields `Just (2*0, 0+1, 2*0+1)`.

The middle value, `0+1` is the value of the root node in your tree. The left subtree is built similarly except `b` is now `2*0`, and the right subtree is built with `b` as `2*0+1`.

---

You mention this is homework which is supposed to build a tree with `2^n - 1` nodes. I'm going to guess that `Leaf` values don't count and that you want to number these nodes in breadth-first order, and hopefully this example gets you in the neighborhood. Here's how to do that:

```
treeBuild :: Int -> Tree Int
treeBuild n = treeUnfold (\b -> if b < 2^n - 1
                                   then Just (2*b+1, b, 2*b+2)
                                   else Nothing) 0
```

The way I arrived at this is by drawing a binary tree with depth 3. I numbered the nodes starting with the root as `0`, the left node as `1` and the right node as `2`. The bottom nodes are numbered from left to right starting with `4` and ending at `7`.

Now the pattern is visible: if the current node is numbered `b`, his left and right nodes are numbered `2*b+1` and `2*b+2` respectively. Since `2^n - 1` is the total number of nodes in a tree of depth `n`, and I'm numbering nodes in breadth-first order, returning `Nothing` when `b >= 2^n-1` ensures I stop after filling the tree up to depth `n`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Problem is when I run the code above, the program would keep looping on forever. I modified the code about slightly so now the right subtree is being built with 2*(b+1) which I think is the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, the recursion will only terminate when `b >= 2^n-1` (that is, `b >= 3`). You start with `b = 0` and the left tree recurses with `b = 2*b` which is still `0`, so it never terminates. You'll need to change either your starting `b` value or the `lt` expression from `2*b`

Comment: I've spent some time trying to figure this out but I still can't seem to get the right solution. `treeUnfold (\b -> if b < 2^(n+1)-1` is what is currently have and this should be the correct value (The number of nodes in a tree would always be `2^(n+1)-1`). Question is how do I actually increment b?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but is `treeBuild n` supposed to build a balanced binary tree whose `2^n-1` nodes are numbered in breadth-first order?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. treeBuild 3 would return `Node (Node (Node Leaf 0 Leaf) 1 (Node Leaf 2 Leaf)) 3 (Node (Node Leaf 4 Leaf) 5 (Node Leaf 6 Leaf))` Basically it starts from 0 on the left and increases as it go towards the right.