# Attempting to construct trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I am trying to use an unfold function to build trees.

```
Tree t = Leaf | Node (Tree t) t (Tree t)

unfoldT :: (b -> Maybe (b, a, b)) -> b -> Tree a
unfoldT f b =
    case f b of
      Nothing -> Leaf
      Just (lt, x, rt) -> Node (unfoldT f lt) x (unfoldT f rt)
```

The build function needs to create a tree that has a height equal to the number provided, as well as be numbered in an in-order fashion. The base case being build 0 = Leaf and the next being build 1 = Node (Leaf 0 Leaf).

```
build :: Integer -> Tree Integer
```

My attempt at solving it:

```
build n = unfoldT (\x -> Just x) [0..2^n-2]
```

I am not entirely sure how to go about constructing the tree here.
Would love it if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Edit 1:

If I was to use a 2-tuple, what would I combine? I need to be able to refer to the current node, its left subtree and its right subtree somehow right?

Comment: Why did you write `[0..n^n-2]` here at the end?

Comment: Hint: use a 2-tuple as `b`.

Comment: Silly me. I corrected it

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15538151/1048572

Comment: In cases like this, it often helps writing an explicit recursive function (with possibly more arguments as needed), and then convert it to a fold later on.

Comment: `Node (Leaf 0 Leaf)` is invalid expression. It should be `(Node Leaf 0 Leaf)` or just `Node Leaf 0 Leaf`.

Answer (score 4):

> If I was to use a 2-tuple, what would I combine?

I would recommend to pass the remaining depth as well as the offset from the left:

```
build = unfoldT level . (0,)
  where
    level (_, 0) = Nothing
    level (o, n) = let mid = 2^(n-1)
                   in ((o, n-1), o+mid-1, (o+mid, n-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I was to use a 2-tuple, what would I combine?

That's the key question behind the state-passing paradigm in functional programming, expressed also with the State Monad. We won't be dealing with the latter here, but maybe use the former.

But before that, do we really need to generate all the numbers in a list, and then work off that list? Don't we know *in advance* what are the numbers we'll be working with?

Of course we do, because the tree we're building is totally balanced and fully populated.

So if we have a function like

```
-- build2 (depth, startNum)
build2 :: (Int, Int) -> Tree Int
```

we can use it *just the same* to construct *both halves* of e.g. the `build [0..14]` tree:

```
build [0..14] == build2 (4,0) == Node (build2 (3,0)) 7 (build2 (3,8))
```

Right?

But if we didn't want to mess with the direct calculations of all the numbers involved, we could arrange for the aforementioned state-passing, with the twist to `build2`'s interface:

```
--     depth, startNum    tree, nextNum
build3 :: (Int, Int) -> (Tree Int, Int)
```

and use it like

```
build :: Int -> Tree Int                 -- correct!
build depth = build3 (depth, 0)          -- intentionally incorrect

build3 :: (Int, Int) -> (Tree Int, Int)  -- correct!
build3 (depth, start) = Node lt n rt     -- intentionally incorrect
  where
       (lt, n) = build3 (depth-1, start)   -- n is returned
       (rt, m) = build3 (depth-1, n+1)     --  and used, next
```

You will need to tweak the above to make all the pieces fit together (*follow the types!*), implementing the missing pieces of course and taking care of the corner / base cases.

Formulating this as an unfold would be the next step.

Comment: I like the idea of passing through the `nextNum` as state (it avoids the repeated calculations that my answer has), but I don't think this approach is doable with `unfold`.

Comment: I haven't thought it through yet... I had this suspicion too but I'm not sure. In any way writing it out this way helps clarify things ,as chi also suggests up in the comments. :)

Comment: or we could produce `Tree (a, next_num_or_something)` as another intermediate step...

Comment: Well you could always create a temporary tree manually and then `unfold` it into the real tree, but that's (ab)using `unfold` as `fmap` and we could just drop it, constructing the proper result in the first place.

Comment: yeah, looks like it is impossible to do with the `unfoldT` as defined in the question. the function `s -> Maybe (s, a, s)` must produce the `a` *and* the two `s`'s at the same time, so it doesn't fit. interesting, this example really shows the difference between recursion and corecursion, on *trees*.